# Warning: fsockopen() unable to connect to ssl://smtp.gmail.com:465 -

Tags: php, wordpress

I am getting this error when i am submitting form. Form should trigger a mail. I tried all the solutions in stackoverflow.

Using Plugin - events-manager-extended

These errors i am getting

> Warning: fsockopen() [function.fsockopen]: unable to connect to
>   ssl://smtp.gmail.com:465 (Unable to find the socket transport "ssl" -
>   did you forget to enable it when you configured PHP?) in
>   site\webroot\wp-content\plugins\events-manager-extended\phpmailer\class-smtp.php
>   on line 122
>
> Fatal error: Call to undefined method SMTP::getError() in
>   site\webroot\wp-includes\class-phpmailer.php on line 2119 PHP Warning:
>   fsockopen() [function.fsockopen]: unable to connect to
>   ssl://smtp.gmail.com:465 (Unable to find the socket transport "ssl" -
>   did you forget to enable it when you configured PHP?) in
>   site\webroot\wp-content\plugins\events-manager-extended\phpmailer\class-smtp.php
>   on line 122 PHP Fatal error: Call to undefined method SMTP::getError()
>   in site\webroot\wp-includes\class-phpmailer.php on line 2119